# Regex match a character that's not part of word in string

Tags: javascript, regex

Using Regex in JS I'm trying to match all `<` and `>` which are not part of a specific HTML element. In the below example, I try to exclude those associated with <sup> and </sup> but my current expression still matches with > at the end of the element.

How can I also exclude the ending > of the element?

Current expression:

```
 /(?!<\/?sup>)[<>]/gi
```

[image: Image of Regex Example]

Comment: Regex is not the right tool to parse HTML. Best to inspect the DOM directly using native JS or jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost there; the special tag can show up before or after a tag, e.g. using ([Demo](https://regex101.com/r/GuzZSa/1/)):

```
(?<!sup)[<>](?!\/?sup)
```

Or if you want to make it more readable: `<(?!\/?sup)|(?<!\/?sup)>`
We could optimize this with possessive quantifiers; unfortunately, JS does not support them.